# how to C# asp.net core redirect / apply IActionResult from inside a task

Tags: c#, task, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am having a razor shown during a long server task.
when that task is finished, I would like to go to another page.
How do I do that?

a pizza ordering site, where the pizza in the own, page should change to out of own, after some time...

```
class PizzaOwnModel:PageModel {   
    ...
    public void OnGet() {
       Task.Factory.CreateNew(()=>   
         bool ready = false
         while (! ready) {   
             Task.Delay(1000);
             ready=IsPizzaFinished(); 
         }
         Redirect("PizzaReadyPage");
       };
       ImageDisplayPath = "wwwroot/images/pizzaInOwn.jpg";
    };

    // and ofcause an <img srv=@Model.ImageDisplayPath> in the 
    // html of the razorpage
```

The in own picture is displayed nicely, and the loop running, but for some odd reason, the redirect to the new page never happens.

Basically the question could probably be narrowed down to how to get an IActionResult to happend when a task in finished/done?

Comment: Do you understand how HTTP works? You can send one response to one request. If you want that response to refresh itself, you need to do so using headers (refresh) or JavaScript (polling).

Comment: probably not ;-)
I was hopping to avoid polling from the client, but was hopping that is there was another way to go..

Comment: Well then there's websockets...

Comment: well, I guess i'll try javascripting, it should be relatively simple..
an ajax call, a redirect, and a setInterval..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
  Response.Redirect("PizzaReadyPage");
```

instead of this :

```
  Redirect("PizzaReadyPage");
```